# Cron (PHP) not running properly

Tags: php, cron

I have a cron

```
0 21 * * * php /var/www/html/site/cron.php/batch 1>>/dev/null 2>&1
```

However it is not working.

When I try

```
php /var/www/html/site/cron.php/batch
```

or

```
/usr/bin/php /var/www/html/site/cron.php/batch
```

It says,

"Could not open input file:"

I see, cron.php is considering cron.php file as a folder and trying to open it. So giving me the error.

Also tried

```
* * * * * nobody wget -O http://example.com/cron.php/batch
```

P.S: `http://example.com/cron.php/batch` works when i access it in the browser.

**Update**: 
I had 755 permission to the file. After getting "Could not open input file:" message, even I thought file permission was the error.

I'm still facing the issue

Comment: The `wget` does not work? That would be the normal solution for calling a script with args that normally expects to be called via http.  What is in the cron.php? can you pass the `batch` argument via a proper CLI argument?  If cron.php was built cleverly, there may be a command line flag like `--batch`

Comment: Also, the `nobody` user may not be supported in every crontab (possibly only system `/etc/crontab`).  It may work for you to run the `wget` as you have it but without `nobody`

Comment: Check the permissions on the PHP script and all the directories in the path, make sure they're world-readable.

Comment: In the version using `wget`, you have a missing `/`: `* * * * * nobody wget -O http://example.com/cron.php/batch`

Comment: Not sure why this deserves 2 downvotes :/

Comment: @EdCottrell It was typo- error here. Not in my server's crontab. corrected in the question now

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Tested with PHP CLI. No use.
Removed user "nobody" and triggered. Still it did not resolve the problem.

Comment: @siva Tested _how_? What specifically did you test? I was asking about what `cron.php` actually does, and if it has a facility to call from the command line to pass the `batch` argument (which you can't do via path `cron.php/batch` on the CLI)

Comment: @Barmar It is not permission issue. Changed the files permission and tried.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski: thanks for your reply. please check barmer's answer below.

Comment: @siva Yes, Barmar is explaining it correctly. I was asking to see the code in `cron.php` to know if it had any facility to be able to read CLI parameters. It apparently does not, and his suggestion for how to add it with `$argv` is sound.

Answer (score 3):

When you run a PHP script from the command line, you can't use additional pathname elements after the script name. Allowing parameters to be put into the pathname is a webserver feature, it doesn't work with ordinary pathnames.

```
php /var/www/html/site/cron.php batch
```

The script should then get the `batch` parameter from `$argv[1]`, not `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']`.

Maybe at the beginning of the script you can do:

```
if (!isset($_SERVER['PATH_INFO']) && isset($argv[1])) {
    $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] = '/' . argv[1];
}
```

Comment: Sorry. I may have misunderstood. 
I executed `php /var/www/html/site/cron.php batch` in ssh and got "error message".
Since the argument is not passed, my code is throwing the error msg.

Comment: You can't generally expect the same script to work both from CLI and from a webserver. CLI doesn't set all the `$_SERVER` variables, there's no `$_POST` or `$_GET`, etc.

Comment: If you want to be able to use the same script, it needs to check how it was invoked, and then use different mechanisms to get parameters.

Comment: I was going through few related question and according to my understanding parameters are for `$_GET or $_POST` variables. 

The thing is, the web app(by ex-employee) had built on some framework.

The Structure is : cron.php contains many **functions** like **batch**, **email** etc. When you access `cron.php/email`, it will execute **email** function in the cron.php file.

Comment: Well, if you want to use it from `cron`, you need to recode it to process parameters from the command line.

Comment: When I execute `php /var/www/html/site/cron.php batch`, batch acts as a parameter/argument without any **function** handler, So it gives error message. I hope, you can understand

Comment: I understand. I've explained the problem. The framework you're using expects to get this parameter from `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']`. That isn't available when you run the script from the CLI, it can only be done from the webserver. There's no simple fix for this, you need to recode the script.

Comment: Thanks !
Sorry to bother again. We should again see check argv[1] exists or not, right?
Because if i load, example.com/cron.php in browser and it will not have PATH_INFO and will throw error since args is also not available.

Comment: Yes, you can do that for extra safety. I just assumed that if you weren't running it from the webserver, you would always provide the parameter.

Comment: Fixed my issue :) Also updated the code to include **`php_sapi_name() === 'cli'`** check in `if` statement.